# Split list in lists of length 1,2,4,8.. using Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to prolog and need to write relation that split list in lists of length 2^1, 2^2, 2^3 ... 2^n, so for example if we have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] we should get [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]] I solved it in Haskell but have no clue how to make it in prolog

```
    blocks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    blocks _ [] = []
    blocks n ls = la : blocks (2*n) lb
            where ~(la,lb) = splitAt n ls
```

Comment: I don't know prolog but have you tried anything? People that help on SO are hesitant to do so if you don't provide more detail that just "this is the problem" or "this is what I'm trying to do" - they want to see some effort.

Comment: @Adam, I wrote this task in Haskell, but have no idea how to convert code in prolog

Comment: It's time to dig into a Prolog textbook or tutorial, get some basics down, then you can get started to try something and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should be easy to follow and learn from (not written with efficiency in mind):

```
split(L, X) :- split(L, 1, X).

split([], _, []).

split(X, N, [X]) :-
    length(X, M),
    M #< N, M #> 0.

split(L, N, [X|Xs]) :-
    N0 #= N * 2,
    length(X, N),
    append(X, R, L),
    split(R, N0, Xs).
```

And here is a version following your Haskell code more closely:

```
split_at_squares(L, X) :-
    split_at_squares_(L, 1, X).

split_at_squares_([],_,[]).
split_at_squares_([L|Ls], I, [X|Xs]) :-
    split_at(I, [L|Ls], X, Xs0),
    J #= I * 2,
    split_at_squares_(Xs0, J, Xs).

split_at(I, L, P, S) :-
    length(L, LL),
    J #= min(I, LL),
    length(P, J),
    append(P, S, L).
```

They both aren't perfect, though. The first one diverges for the most general query and the second one doesn't terminate universally in the other direction. Any tips how to improve them are appreciated.